# adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing... On MacOS

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I am looking my problem solution. I try many method to solve this problem. ( I am using MacOS)

I am trying to run Flutter Demo App on Android Studio before the updating everything working perfectly. But now I have problem with adb server.

When I run the app on my Phone with Device Manager I get below errors:

```
    Launching lib/main.dart on SM A525F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
* daemon started successfully
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
Error: ADB exited with exit code 1
Performing Streamed Install

adb: failed to install /Users/duygu/StudioProjects/android_test/build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk:
Error launching application on SM A525F.
```

So What I have try:

I open the adb file location: `cd /Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools`

and run this commands:

```
./adb kill-server
./adb start-server
```

There is nothing to changed.
And than I add adb path to my.bash_profile file:

```
export PATH=Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH

export PATH="$PATH:/Users/duygu/development/flutter/bin"
```

And than it does not work.And than I create bashrc file with nano ~/.bashrc

than I add to this path here

```
export PATH=/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/tools:$PATH
export PATH=/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools:$PATH
```

And run this command `source ~/.bashrc` than run `which adb` command

I get: `/Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`

And again I have same issue. How can I solve this problem please help

This is the flutter doctor -v output:

```
 flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.4, on macOS 12.3.1 21E258 darwin-arm, locale tr-TR)
    • Flutter version 2.10.4 at /Users/duygu/development/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision c860cba910 (4 weeks ago), 2022-03-25 00:23:12 -0500
    • Engine revision 57d3bac3dd
    • Dart version 2.16.2
    • DevTools version 2.9.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/duygu/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.2.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+0-b60-7772763)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.64.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.36.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 100.0.4896.88
    ! Device RXXXXXXXX is not authorized.
      You might need to check your device for an authorization dialog.

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. The reason was, I had installed a sharing display app called 'Splashtop XDisplay', then I removed that app, the app had adb,
there was conflict between that adb and Android Studio adb.

Answer (score 1):

I just hit this problem. It was caused by having multiple Android SDKs installed... in my case I have the normal one at `~/Library/Android/sdk` and several other versions inside various Unity installations.

Now, I had Android Studio running which had open a project referencing one of the older Unity-based Android SDK. Every time I killed `adb` from the command-line, Android Studio would quietly spin up a new instance - using the old Android SDK. So when I tried my next `adb` command - using the normal SDK - it would find an incompatible version already running: `adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing...`

The solution was just to close Android Studio to stop it instantly spinning up an out of date adb before I could start the right one.

Answer (score 0):

what worked for me.

My Android Studio has an adb file inside /home/myuser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/ and with the version 1.0.41.

Note where I put myuser could be your name, whatever, just locate your Android path.

My error was:
adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (39)

When you type just adb in terminal, this command will be related with the adb archive inside /usr/bin.

So, I did these steps inside terminal:

1.adb version
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.39

2.cd /usr/bin

3.sudo rm adb

4.cd /home/myuser/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/

5.Please check if there is an adb file inside your path

6.Now copy to /usr/bin

sudo cp adb /usr/bin

7.adb version again Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41

With this done, right now I have the same adb file to both of them, so, if in the future the SDK Manager ask to upgrade platform-tools, remember to do it again if the error back to appear.

Comment: there is any adb in /usr/bin location I checked

Comment: Also I am looking solution. I expecting answers

Comment: I'm still having ```adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing...```any new solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this issue is that,

1 - download the Android SDK Platform-tools version that contain adb version 41 from [download site](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Platformtools) 
2 - replace the folder Platform-tools in C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk with the new one.

3 - from your emulator screen "mobile screen" look at the left options,in the bottom there is three dots "..." click on these dots then "setting" then switch off "Use Detected ADB location", then click on the left folder to locate your db.exe manually chose the file you put in C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\db.exe

restart your software .

Thats all, enjoy

Answer (score 0):

1. download the Android SDK Platform-tools version that contain adb version 41 from [download site](https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/Platformtools)
2. replace the folder Platform-tools in `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk` with the new one.
3. from your emulator screen `mobile screen` look at the left options, in the bottom there is three dots `...` click on these dots then `setting` then switch off `Use Detected ADB location`, then click on the left folder to locate your db.exe manually chose the file you put in `C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\db.exe`

restart your software .

Thats all, enjoy